# A is targeting to B, B and C are targeting to A. If A is hit then find the probability that B hits the target and C does not.

Tags: probability

A is targeting to B, B and C are targeting to A

The probability of hitting the target by A, B and C are 2/3,1/2 and 1/3 respectively.

If A is hit then find the probability that B hits the target and C does not.

Note: I know the original method by bayers theorem, the answer is 1/2

but

**MY doubt is**- Is there any innovative solution this problem,I mean as far as I can think I think of making a Unit square at first with 2 regions A hit and A not hit but not able to proceed.

Given below is the traditional way for finding the answer

[image: Traditional method]

Comment: I'm not sure this is clear.  Are they all shooting at the same time?  Does $A$  get a shot at $B$ before $B$ fires?

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question.  If $A$ shoots first, then $B$ is dead with high probability so the matter is (nearly) decided.  If $A$ doesn't shoot first...well, what then what relevance does his $\frac 23$ accuracy have?  Should say:  either way, I don't see $\frac 12$ as the answer.

Comment: My friend the question is: Given that A is dead (he didn't shoot anyone)

find the probability that he is hit by B and not C

Comment: Ok...if you assume that $A$ didn't shoot for some reason then the probability that $A$ is hit (by someone) is $P(B)+P(C)-P(B\cap C)=\frac 12+\frac 13-\frac 16=\frac 23$.  the probability that $B$ hits but $C$ does not is $\frac 12\times \frac 13=\frac 16$ so Bayes tells us the answer is the ratio, which comes to $\frac 14$.

Comment: Sorry, my error.  The numerator in that case is $\frac 12\times \frac 23=\frac 13$ so I agree that the answer, under the assumption that $A$ forgets to shoot is $\frac 12$.

Comment: My doubt is regarding the intuitive way to prove that using a unit square and perhaps the area method, my prof. did it last year but he doesn't teach us anymore so I am in search of that proof for the better understanding of probability